# Get category ID in Magento Footer

Tags: php, magento

I want to get current category ID in magento Footer area so that I can create a condition where certain things are not shown in that specific category. For example I want to do:
if current category is 111
do not show the social icons

I tried the following code:

```
<?php$current_id=  Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();echo $current_id;?>
```

Problem with the above code is that it echo a random ID and it doesnt change I go thru different categories.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? Mage::registry('current_category')

Answer (score 4):

When you don’t have access to $this, you can use Magento registry:

```
$category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

OR

Get the variable  set on the Block for xml

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getCategoryId()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current category details from registry:

```
 $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
```

To get the category id:

```
 $category_id= Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

But you must not apply cache on the footer -- please refer to this [stackexchange link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/do-not-cache-footer).